# Synchronous play of several players in AUGraph

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiounit, audiotoolbox

I use AUGraph, which contains several (10, for example) players, mixer and output.
If I turn on players with delay about 0,2sec - it's ok, they all play, but if I turn on them at the same time, only 3-4 players play.

It's ok, all players play, but with delay:

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       [players[i] play];
       usleep(200000);
    }
```

It's not ok, only 2-3 players play, but synchronously:

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       [players[i] play];
    }
```

In `[player play]` method:

```
   AudioTimeStamp startTime;
   memset (&startTime, 0, sizeof(startTime));
   startTime.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
   startTime.mSampleTime = -1;

   AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
      kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp, 
      kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
      0, 
      &startTime, 
      sizeof(startTime));
```

`AudioUnitSetProperty` returns noErr.

It seems that there is conflict in AudioUnitSetProperty with several threads, which I can't control.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFilePrime setup before kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp solved a problem.

```
    UInt32 defaultVal = 0;
    AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                         kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFilePrime,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                         0,
                         &defaultVal,
                         sizeof(defaultVal));
```